# CSS: Overriding a property with display-inline makes text unselectable in IE

Tags: css

Tested this on IE11;

html:

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="test">some text</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.test {
   display: inline-block;
}

.bar .test {
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pjWjy/117/

So we define a class `test` with property `display: inline-block`. Then we override the class with `display: inline`. And You cannot select the text in IE. Works ok in the other browsers. If there is no override of properties (remove either one of the classes) everything works as expected. Is this a bug in IE ? Cannot find it documented. Any ideas how can I fix this, without removing the override of properties ?

Comment: strange but true !!!

Comment: but why would you want to override the style inline-block with inline?

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange issue!

I have applied position absolute and its working after that

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjWjy/120/)

```
   .test {
      display: inline-block;
   }
   .bar .test {
      display: inline;
      position:absolute;
   }
```

Also found this article about text selection issue in ie -

[How to prevent (or enable) text selection on your webpage using CSS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152140(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: float: left is better solution but in more complicated example, it breaks other things